# How is the name field of ParameterDescriptor used by declare_parameter?

Tags: ros, ros2, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first parameter you pass into every version of `declare_parameter` is the name of the parameter.  If you also specify a name value in the `ParameterDescriptor` how is it used?  Should the name field of the `ParameterDescriptor` be not set when using it to call `declare_parameter`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/378427/how-is-the-name-field-of-parameterdescriptor-used-by-declare_parameter?/) by [tylerjw](https://answers.ros.org/users/58958/tylerjw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2021-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I thought this is an interesting question so I had a look around. Firstly, the [documentation of `declare_parameter`](https://docs.ros2.org/foxy/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1Node.html#a095ea977b26e7464d9371efea5f36c42) states:

> The name and type in the given rcl_interfaces::msg::ParameterDescriptor are ignored, and should be specified using the name argument to this function and the default value's type instead.

When we look through the code, we can see that the descriptor name is indeed always overridden by the name value passed as the first argument ([here](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/1c617515403db16b8cbabd834073eaca0f9a452d/rclcpp/src/rclcpp/node_interfaces/node_parameters.cpp#L355) for parameters that do not have a default/initial value and [here](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/1c617515403db16b8cbabd834073eaca0f9a452d/rclcpp/src/rclcpp/node_interfaces/node_parameters.cpp#L318) for parameters that do):

```
parameter_infos[name].descriptor.name = name;
```

Trying to set a different name in the descriptor for different variants of `declare_parameter` like so:

```
auto param1 = declare_parameter("param1");

auto param2_desc = rcl_interfaces::msg::ParameterDescriptor{};
param2_desc.name = "param2desc";
auto param2 = declare_parameter<int>("param2", 0, param2_desc);

auto param3_desc = rcl_interfaces::msg::ParameterDescriptor{};
param3_desc.name = "param3desc";
auto param3 = declare_parameter<int>("param3", rclcpp::ParameterType::PARAMETER_INTEGER, param3_desc);

auto param4_desc = rcl_interfaces::msg::ParameterDescriptor{};
param3_desc.name = "param4desc";
auto param4 = declare_parameter<int>("param4", rclcpp::PARAMETER_NOT_SET, param4_desc);
```

and then listing them, shows that indeed in each case the name given in the descriptor is ignored:

```
$ ros2 param list
/param_name_test:
  param1
  param2
  param3
  param4
```

As for why this seeming redundancy is there I couldn't directly find a source, but I'd hazard the guess that it is to enforce providing a name (and type).

When you run `ros2 describe /yournode yourparam`, what happens underneath is that [the hidden `describe_parameters` service is called on `yournode`](https://github.com/ros2/ros2cli/blob/edbc1600aa161845c58138bc18907bd873670a54/ros2param/ros2param/api/__init__.py#L164-L186), which returns [a list of `ParameterDescriptor`](https://github.com/ros2/rcl_interfaces/blob/c5d0a20150533a6cb93d5dcbd6e27cea9300aa6e/rcl_interfaces/srv/DescribeParameters.srv#L5-L8)s.
This is the same `ParameterDescriptor` message type as that you can pass into `declare_parameter`. So this message type needs to have al the information in it, including the parameter name.

However, ROS 2 messages do not have a way to enforce that all values are set; you could create an empty descriptor like `ParamaterDescriptor{}` and pass it in, which would have an empty string as the default value for `name`. ROS 2 could check this at runtime and throw an exception, but it's better to catch this earlier, which is I suspect why it forces you to give the name (and type) explicitly and then set that on the descriptor, so that you can't forget, or at least so that the compiler will already tell you much sooner.

It *is* of course still possible to erroneously pass an empty string as name, and ROS 2 [does check for that at runtime](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/1c617515403db16b8cbabd834073eaca0f9a452d/rclcpp/src/rclcpp/node_interfaces/node_parameters.cpp#L408-L410), but it's much harder to do that accidentally.

---

Originally posted by [sgvandijk](https://answers.ros.org/users/72841/sgvandijk/) with karma: 649 on 2021-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1